# Removes values in a file that match patterns from another file

Tags: bash, unix

I have a list of values in one file:

```
item2
item3
item4
```

and I want to remove the entire line from another file when the rows looks like this:

```
item1|XXXX|ABCD
item2|XXXX|ABCD
item3|XXXX|ABCD
item4|XXXX|ABCD
item5|XXXX|ABCD
```

So that I'm left with:

```
item1|XXXX|ABCD
item5|XXXX|ABCD
```

Is there a `bash` sequence to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`grep -vf` can do the job:

```
grep -vFf file1 file2
item1|XXXX|ABCD
item5|XXXX|ABCD
```

Answer (score 2):

If your distinctive marker is that `|XXXX|ABCD|` string, you can just `grep` it out:

```
$ grep -vF '|XXXX|ABCD|' input > output
```

It's safer to use option `-F` (fixed strings) because your pattern is dangerously close to containing regex metacharacters (namely in your case: `|`—it's not active in the default `grep` regex syntax, but you don't want to worry about that when you're working with simple patterns).

If your distinctive pattern is the rest of the line, you can use a whole file as a pattern list with `grep`'s `-f` option:

```
$ grep -vFf item_list < input > output
```

Answer (score 2):

awk to the rescue!

```
$ awk -F"|" 'NR==FNR{a[$1];next} !($1 in a)' remove items
item1|XXXX|ABCD
item5|XXXX|ABCD
```

where the item list to be removed is in file "remove" and data in file "items"